# What provisions existed in UK law for handling a tied Brexit vote?

Tags: united-kingdom, constitutional-law

The UK left the European Union because of a public referendum where [51.8% of the votes were in favour in leaving the EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causes_of_the_vote_in_favour_of_Brexit#:%7E:text=Factors%20included%20sovereignty%2C%20immigration%2C%20the,of%20leaving%20the%20European%20Union.).

Suppose it had resulted in an tie, i.e. 50% in favour of leaving the EU, 50% against leaving the EU.

What legal framework existed at the time for handling such a tie? Would the government have been required to run the referendum a second time? Would they have settled it with a coin flip? Or was there no law about this possibility at all?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This election was held years ago

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I disagree. Either there was a legal requirement that the referendum would be run again in the case of a tie, or there was not; either way, the question can be answered with reference to the law. "What would the politicians have done if the vote tied" is a separate question that does not invalidate this one. Though perhaps the question could be improved to make that distinction clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the whole regulations on [www.legislation.gov.uk](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/41/contents).

It is a referendum. There does not need to be a "winner". A referendum is meant to understand what the general populace *wants*. And "they are split exactly 50/50 between X and Y" is a valid result in that frame.

The point that made this referendum special was that the ruling party had promised, that they would actually *do* what the referendums outcome would suggest, even if they were *not* legally bound by it and were not even in favor of it as a political party.

So what the ruling party would have done when confronted by an absolute exact tie (not only percentages, but actual votes) is anybodies guess. I don't think anybody had a backup plan for what happens if the 33,577,342 votes came out *exactly* 16,788,671 to 16,788,671. The chance of that... was not real. You prepare for that about as much as for an alien invasion on election day.

Comment: Thanks. If it is a even number there can be a tie but not for a odd number of votes. In this case there can be a tie which could be rare. 33,577,342

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar You are looking at 51.8% vs. 48.2%. There are 1 208 780 votes more for leaving than staying. The chance for exactly 50/50 in an election with that many votes is **1** in a number of possibilities that has more than a million zeros. You are looking at a chance of $\frac{1}{33,5*10^6!}$ - that is 1 difived by the factorial of 33.5 million...

Comment: Technically it was a plebiscite, not a referendum. A referendum is legally binding, which, given the UK’s doctrine of parliamentary sovereignty is not possible there. While this particular plebiscite was politically binding, that didn’t make it a referendum.

Comment: Thanks. This could be the rarest case where probability could be 0.000000001 for the votes tie. But still, revoting?